# How to find indices in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python

If I have the loop

```
for x in multidimensional_array:  
    # do something here
```

Can I find i, j such that x = multidimensional_array[i][j]?

Comment: What's `multidimensional_array`? Is it a list of lists? A NumPy array? In any case I can think of, this is going to iterate over the rows, so `x = multidimensional_array[i][j]` probably won't hold for any i and j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple nested loops:

```
for row in range(len(multidimensional_array)):
    for column in range(len(multidimensional_array[row])):
        if multidimensional_array[row][column] == x:
            <hand the row and column information>
            break
```

This will search all of the lists within the 2D list, and then search every item within that internal list, and if that item at the row,column position matches what your 'x' is, doing something with it.

Comment: I originally had this in my code, but wanted to change it to an element based for loop.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @NoOneinParticular if you want the indices, this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through a multidimentional list in Python, you will get a series of lists, not the elements of those lists. For example, the following code:

```
for i in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]:
    print(i)
```

Will output this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

A good way to iterate through a multidimentional list is by using nested loops, such as in the following example:

```
stuff = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

for i in range(len(stuff)):
    iList = stuff[i]
    for j in range(len(iList)):
        jElement = iList[j]
        print("At i=" + str(i) + " and j=" + str(j) + ", we find " + str(jElement))
```

Which would print:

```
At i=0 and j=0, we find 1
At i=0 and j=1, we find 2
At i=0 and j=2, we find 3
At i=1 and j=0, we find 4
At i=1 and j=1, we find 5
At i=1 and j=2, we find 6
```

In order to find the indices of element `x`, you could make use of the `list.index` function:

```
def find(multi, x):
    for i in range(len(multi)):
        nested = multi[i]
        try:
            return i, nested.index(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError("Element not found")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(Row in multiArray){
   for(Col in Row){
      //Col is x in this case
   }
} 
//A java example would be like this
int[][] multiArray = {(blabla),(blabla)}
for(int[] row: multiArray){
   for(int col: row){
      print(col); // Col is the x that you are looking for.
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.